# How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a small number of static sites where I simply want to hide the `.html` extension:

- the URL `/foo` fetches the static file `/foo.html`
- the browser still displays the URL `/foo`

The client can then send out bookmarks in the style `example.com/foo` rather than `example.com/foo.html`.

It sounds very simple, and I've used `mod_rewrite` happily before (say with WordPress or for redirects), but this is proving much harder to crack that I thought. Perhaps I'm missing something really obvious, but I can't find a solution anywhere and I've been at it all day!

We run our own server, so this can go wherever is the best place.

**Addendum**

The solution checked below worked fine. Then after running the site awhile I noticed two problems:

1. all pages began to appear unstyled. I reloaded, cleared the cache, etc., but still no-style. I've had this trouble before, and can't locate the source.
2. There's a directory AND an HTML file named 'gallery', so the /gallery link shows a directory listing instead of the HTML file. I should be able to sort that one, but further tips welcome :-)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

This will rewrite all requests that can be mapped to an existing file when appending a `.html`.

Comment: Thanks! Just changed the pattern to '(.[a-z]+)' as all the html files contain only those chars. New problems now, worst one is no CSS (this initially appeared on reload, then toggled styles on and off, now all files are unstyled so I guess the earlier views were getting a cached CSS file?).

Comment: @DaveEveritt I'm having the same CSS problem, only when I append a trailing slash to the URL, in which case all relative links are considered to be in a subdirectory, including the CSS. Did you find a way to fix it?

Comment: @LazloBonin One solution is not to use absolute paths instead of relative paths. Or explicitly set a base URL with an appropriate path so that relative paths are resolved from the base URL path instead of the current URL path.

Comment: I had a number on the file name, and it did not work. Just alerting.

Comment: @Lazlo - (late reply, I know) no I didn't solve it, and gave up after attempts produced very unpredictable results. Then swapped to using static site generator nanoc, which gets around the issue I wanted to solve (with an index file in a directory for each page).

Comment: Shouldn't the `!.*\.html$` part in the RewriteRule be changed to maybe just `^`. What is the benefit of it? You are already checking if the file exists in the `RewriteCond`, and you aren't using the result of the pattern in the substitution string. It does have a drawback, if file named for example `filename.html.html` you cannot open it with `/filename.html` (Though I don't know why would anyone would have this use case, but it is interesting to note)

Comment: Quick question, what is the purpose of the `!` in your RewriteRule?

Comment: @AshMenon That’s the negation operator: Only apply if the following is not matched.

Comment: So if I'm understand it correctly, your first line is a Rule to check that the file (requested filename with ".html" appended) exists, and the second line applies to anything that DOESN'T end with ".html" and rewrites it to the appended equivalent?

Comment: @AshMenon The rule means: only append `.html` if it's not already ends with `.html` and if the resulting file exists.

Comment: What file do I change? I don't know where to paste this code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MichaelJancen-Widmer this code goes in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Don't forget to `RewriteEngine on`

Answer (score 41):

The previous answers don't check if the requested path is a directory.

Here is the full rewrite condition which doesn't rewrite, if requested path is a directory (as stated by the original question):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d          # is not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f     # is an existing html file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html                   # rewrite index to index.html
```

To be SEO friendly and avoid double content, redirect the `.html` URLs:

```
# Redirects example.com/file.html to example.com/file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d          # is not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f     # is an existing html file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\.html$      # request URI ends with .html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]        # redirect from index.html to index
```

If you need the same for scripts take a look here:
[How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028025/how-can-i-use-htaccess-to-hide-php-url-extensions)

Comment: Do I need to include both of these rules or just the last one?  The first one loads the /index and shows the index.html file.  But including the second block doesn't redirect /index.html back to /index for the duplicate content.

Comment: You need both rule blocks. The first one rewrites `index` to `index.html` internally so the user can't see it. The second block does a 301 redirect from `index.html` to `index`.

Comment: Note that - at least as of Apache 2.2.23 - inline comments are apparently NOT supported, so the above definitions will break the `.htaccess` file and result in a `500` error, unless you remove the inline comments.

Comment: If I use your definitions unmodified, a path ending in '.html' is NOT redirected. If I remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f` from the *2nd* block, I end up with a redirect loop (as of Apache 2.2.23).

Comment: If I understand the OP's question correctly, he's looking for a *file* to take precedence over a *directory* of the same name; your solution does the opposite.

Comment: The SEO solution above does not work (as a couple of others have noted). Try `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ (/[^\ ]*)\.html[?\ ]` followed by `RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]` instead - works for me :)

Comment: @PaddyMann, why do you need the first `RewriteCond`? It apparently checks to see if the request ended in `.html`. But isn't that what the rule part of the `RewriteRule` itself does? Isn't the `RewriteCond` redundant?

Answer (score 19):

The accepted solution do not works when the website is configured with a virtual host / document root.

There is the solution I used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at this post http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/ I haven't tried it yet but the demonstration seems pretty convincing.

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Wow, I have seldom seen such an issue for which there exists so many "solutions" on the web, where people just throw up what "works for them" but for which few take time to read the documentation to figure out what it does. Many of the solutions given here don't work for virtual hosts, for example.

After much cross-referencing and reading, I want to contribute my own solution that "works for me". Hopefully it works for you, too. I didn't create it from scratch; I was inspired by all the other contributions (even though most of them did not "work for me" without modification).

```
RewriteEngine on

#if foo requested, return foo.html contents
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

#redirect foo.html to foo
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1 [R,L]
```

The `[R]` flag by default does a temporary (302) redirect; if you want a permanent redirect, use `R=301` in place of `R`.

Comment: tried this, same issues! Never mind as I'm rewriting the site, thanks anyway :-)

Comment: For me, this redirects to the entire path to the file (e.g. `/index.html` becomes `/var/www/htdoc/index`)

Comment: It did not work ... now it keeps redirecting index.html to root directory. How do I get it fixed?

Answer (score 3):

To remove `.html` extension from `.*.html` requests, you can use the following script in `root/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#1) externally redirect "/file.html" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
#2) rewrite  "/file" back to "/file.html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks, although this is an old question and I use [Nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/) (a static site generator) for sites like this. I tried this, but the spin-off problem remains - my styles completely disappear.

Comment: You are welcome @DaveEveritt !



To fix your style, js ,images and other relative resources on rewritten urls, you can add a base tag to head section of your webpage `<base href="/">` for more info..read my answer on this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Comment: Tried again but still no joy. It's an old site and I was using SSI (so changed .html to .shtml in your example) and had already moved all the main subsections into their own directories, but non-index .shtml pages inside those directories get their containing dir stripped from the URL so 404, and "/styles/body.css" still fails to load throughout the site. Anyway, thanks for the tips, but I'll abandon this now as the site will be remade at some point!

Answer (score 3):

> - the url /foo fetches the static file /foo.html
> - the browser still displays the url /foo

Apache can do this without `mod_rewrite`, see documentation:

**Multiviews**

> The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Source: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which allows us to store the file on disk as:

```
foo.html.php
```

But in the browser, refer to it as

```
foo.html
```

To make this work for you, I think you would just need to modify it a bit to match your existing requests, and check for an actual file in place with the `.html` extension.

```
 # These are so we do not need the .php extension
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (\.xul|\.html|\.xhtml|\.xml)$',
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f',
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php',
```