# Remove .php extension with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Yes, I've read the Apache manual and searched here. For some reason I simply cannot get this to work. The closest I've come is having it remove the extension, but it points back to the root directory. I want this to just work in the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

I need to do three things with the `.htaccess` file.

1. I need it to remove the `.php`

a. I have several pages that use tabs and the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) looks like `page.php#tab` - is this possible?

b. I have one page that uses a session ID appended to the URL to make sure you came from the right place, `www.domain.example/download-software.php?abcdefg`.

Is this possible? Also in doing this, do I need to remove `.php` from the links in my header nav include file? Should `IE "<a href="support.php">support</a>" be <a href="support">support</a>?`

2. I would like it to force `www` before every URL, so it's not `domain.example`, but `www.domain.example/page`.
3. I would like to remove all trailing slashes from pages.

I'll keep looking, trying, etc. Would being in a sub directory cause any issues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove file extension from website address? (sample photos attached)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address-sample-photos-attached)

Comment: I'm just curious, what benefit is this? Is this so that your users don't know what file on your server they're accessing?

Comment: two fold. so they dont know what file types we are serving, and it just looks cleaner IMO

Comment: Another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534904/how-to-remove-file-extension-from-website-address .

Comment: If none of the solutions provided below work. You can check out this post https://helponnet.com/2020/02/04/remove-html-and-php-extension-with-htaccess-rewriterule-url-rewriting-tips/ And learn from their how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Gumbo's answer in the Stack Overflow question *[How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite/1992191#1992191)* should work fine.

Re 1) Change the .html to .php

Re a.) Yup, that's possible, just add `#tab` to the URL.

Re b.) That's possible using `QSA` (Query String Append), see below.

This *should* also work in a sub-directory path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thx for your help man, for whatever reason, Id bet due to the session appended url being hardcoded in the PHP file (long story) I am able to access it without the above. I really appreciate your help, this .htaccess stuff is tricky for me.

Comment: @Pekka웃  remove space between `[L,` space `QSA]` flags, otherwise _500 Internal Server Error_ will cause.

Comment: this will make `/index/bla/bla` to be the same as `index.php`

Comment: ! means not. That rule says to only rewrite to add .php if it doesn't already end in .php

Answer (score 77):

## Apache mod_rewrite

What you're looking for is [mod_rewrite](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html),

> Description: Provides a rule-based rewriting engine to rewrite
> requested URLs on the fly.

Generally speaking, `mod_rewrite` works by matching the requested document against specified regular expressions, then performs URL rewrites internally (within the Apache process) or externally (in the clients browser). These rewrites can be as simple as internally translating `example.com/foo` into a request for `example.com/foo/bar`.

The Apache docs include a `mod_rewrite` guide and I think some of the things you want to do are covered in it. [Detailed mod_rewrite guide](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

## Force the `www` subdomain

> I would like it to force "www" before every URL, so its not `domain.example` but `www.domain.example/page`

The rewrite guide includes instructions for this under the [Canonical Hostname](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost) example.

## Remove trailing slashes (Part 1)

> I would like to remove all trailing slashes from pages

I'm not sure why you would want to do this as the rewrite guide includes [an example for the exact opposite](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#trailingslash), i.e., always including a trailing slash. The docs suggest that removing the trailing slash has great potential for causing issues:

> Trailing Slash Problem
>
> Description:
>
> Every webmaster can sing a song about the problem of the trailing
> slash on URLs referencing directories. If they are missing, the server
> dumps an error, because if you say `/~quux/foo` instead of `/~quux/foo/`
> then the server searches for a file named foo. And because this file
> is a directory it complains. Actually it tries to fix it itself in
> most of the cases, but sometimes this mechanism need to be emulated by
> you. For instance after you have done a lot of complicated URL
> rewritings to CGI scripts etc.

Perhaps you could expand on why you want to remove the trailing slash all the time?

## Remove `.php` extension

> I need it to remove the .php

The closest thing to doing this that I can think of is to internally rewrite every request document with a .php extension, i.e., `example.com/somepage` is instead processed as a request for `example.com/somepage.php`. Note that proceeding in this manner would would require that each somepage actually exists as somepage.php on the filesystem.

With the right combination of regular expressions this should be possible to some extent. However, I can foresee some possible issues with index pages not being requested correctly and not matching directories correctly.

For example, this will correctly rewrite `example.com/test` as a request for `example.com/test.php`:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

But will make `example.com` fail to load because there is no `example.com/.php`

I'm going to guess that if you're removing all trailing slashes, then picking a request for a directory index from a request for a filename in the parent directory will become almost impossible. How do you determine a request for the directory 'foobar':

```
example.com/foobar
```

from a request for a file called foobar (which is actually foobar.php)

```
example.com/foobar
```

It might be possible if you used the [`RewriteBase`](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive. But if you do that then this problem gets way more complicated as you're going to require [`RewriteCond`](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) directives to do filesystem level checking if the request maps to a directory or a file.

That said, if you remove your requirement of removing all trailing slashes and instead force-add trailing slashes the "no .php extension" problem becomes a bit more reasonable.

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

This still isn't perfect -- *every* request for a file still has .php appended to the request internally. A request for 'hi.txt' will put this in your error logs:

```
[Tue Oct 26 18:12:52 2010] [error] [client 71.61.190.56] script '/var/www/test.peopleareducks.com/rewrite/hi.txt.php' not found or unable to stat
```

But there is another option, set the `DefaultType` and `DirectoryIndex` directives like this:

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

*Update 2013-11-14 - Fixed the above snippet to incorporate nicorellius's observation*

Now requests for hi.txt (and anything else) are successful, requests to `example.com/test` will return the processed version of test.php, and index.php files will work again.

I must give credit where credit is due for this solution as I found it [Michael J. Radwins Blog](http://www.radwin.org/michael/blog/2002/11/hiding_php_extensions_in_a.html) by searching Google for *php no extension apache*.

## Remove trailing slashes

Some searching for `apache remove trailing slashes` brought me to some Search Engine Optimization pages. Apparently some Content Management Systems (Drupal in this case) will make content available with and without a trailing slash in URLs, which in the SEO world will cause your site to incur a duplicate content penalty. [Source](http://blamcast.net/articles/drupal-seo)

The solution seems fairly trivial, using [`mod_rewrite`](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) we rewrite on the condition that the requested resource ends in a `/` and rewrite the URL by sending back the `301 Permanent Redirect` HTTP header.

Here's his example which assumes your domain is blamcast.net and allows the the request to optionally be prefixed with `www.`.

```
#get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?blamcast\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now we're getting somewhere. Lets put it all together and see what it looks like.

## Mandatory `www.`, no `.php`, and no trailing slashes

This assumes the domain is `foobar.example` and it is running on the standard port 80.

```
# Process all files as PHP by default
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
# Fix sub-directory requests by allowing 'index' as a DirectoryIndex value
DirectoryIndex index index.html

# Force the domain to load with the www subdomain prefix
# If the request doesn't start with www...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.foobar\.com [NC]
# And the site name isn't empty
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
# Finally rewrite the request: end of rules, don't escape the output, and force a 301 redirect
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.foobar.example/$1 [L,R,NE]

#get rid of trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?foobar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The 'R' flag is described in the [`RewriteRule`](//httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) directive section. Snippet:

> `redirect|R [=code]` (force redirect) Prefix Substitution with
> `http://thishost[:thisport]/` (which makes the new URL a URI) to force
> a external redirection. If no code is given, a HTTP response of 302
> (*MOVED TEMPORARILY*) will be returned.

## Final Note

I wasn't able to get the slash removal to work successfully. The redirect ended up giving me infinite redirect loops. After reading [the original solution](http://blamcast.net/articles/drupal-seo) closer I get the impression that the example above works for them because of how their Drupal installation is configured. He mentions specifically:

> On a normal Drupal site, with clean URLs enabled, these two addresses
> are basically interchangeable

In reference to URLs ending with and without a slash. Furthermore,

> Drupal uses a file called `.htaccess` to tell your web server how to
> handle URLs. This is the same file that enables Drupal's clean URL
> magic. By adding a simple redirect command to the beginning of your
> `.htaccess` file, you can force the server to automatically remove any
> trailing slashes.

Comment: wow thanks for all that. Actually I was able to get it to work, turns out there was some weird stuff on my server I had to change. Anyway, now onto the next problem, removing the .php from all pages except one. thx man

Comment: I love seeing well thought out, organized answers. Nice work... One thing I noticed: did you mean `DirectoryIndex index index.html`? or `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`?

Comment: @nicorellius believe you are correct. I have updated my original answer with your observation.

Comment: I must say this does not always work. Try the answer below (of user 1079877)

Comment: You are the real MVP.

Comment: Nothing worked for me till I added `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`

Comment: @ÍhorMé Specifically, only `FollowSymLinks` is required (`Indexes` enables directory listings, which you probably don't want to enable). Although `FollowSymLinks` is the default value, so if you are having to enable this then it's been overridden (or removed) earlier in the config.

Comment: First time got this to work! Years looking for such configuration.
index.php, index.html works
/ in the end of path works
Files file.php can be accessed using both file.php and file 
- replay of above:
    # Turn on the rewrite engineRewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]`

Answer (score 65):

In addition to other answers above,

You may also try this  to remove `.php` extensions completely from your file and to avoid **infinite loop**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

This code will work in Root/.htaccess,
Be sure to change the RewriteBase if you want to place this to a htaccess file in sub directory.

On Apache 2.4 and later, you can also use the END flag to prevent infinite loop error. The following example works same as the above on Apache 2.4,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: Unlike the others, this one also works with folders (both example.com/1 (php file) and example.com/2/ (folder) work), however the redirection breaks forms.

Answer (score 27):

The following code works fine for me:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: This works except example.com turns into an index of all files and directories. (Apache 2.4)

Answer (score 16):

I've ended up with the following working code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 15):

After changing the parameter `AllowOverride` from `None` to `All` in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (Debian 8), following [this](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.apache.multiviews), the .htaccess file just must contain:

```
Options +MultiViews
AddHandler php5-script php
AddType text/html php
```

And it was enough to hide .php extension from files

Comment: Wish this one was higher up. Why bother with the overhead of URL rewriting when `MultiViews` does this out-of-the-box

Comment: This is great. Any drawbacks?

Comment: @reformed Thanks. I had to change links from `<a href="somepage.php">`link`</a>` to `<a href="somepage">`link`</a>` in the source code

Comment: `MultiViews` effectively enables extensionless URLs on _everything_. All your static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc) will also be accessible both with and without the file extension. However, one of the biggest "drawbacks" are unexpected conflicts with mod_rewrite, because MultiViews (mod_negotiation) is processed first and effectively rewrites the URL before handing the "rewritten" URL to mod_rewrite. This can cause the mod_rewrite directives to not match the request you are expecting. @reformed

Comment: Still works 2022

Answer (score 14):

Here's a method if you want to do it for just one specific file:

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

Ref: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/remove-file-extention-from-urls/

Answer (score 10):

**Try this**
The following code will definitely work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure why the other answers didn't work for me but this code I found did:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That is all that is in my htaccess and `example.com/page` shows `example.com/page.php`

Answer (score 5):

To remove the `.php` extension from a PHP file for example `yoursite.example/about.php` to `yoursite.example/about`: Open .htaccess (create new one if not exists) file from root of your website, and add the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

To remove the `.html` extension from a HTML file for example `yoursite.example/about.html` to `yoursite.example/about`: Open .htaccess (create new one if not exists) file from root of your website, and add the following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Reference: [How to Remove PHP Extension from URL](http://codemarts.com/blog/how-to-remove-php-extention-from-url/)

Comment: This breaks folders.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource." Please explain this

Answer (score 2):

If you're coding in PHP and want to remove .php so you can have a URL like:

`http://yourdomain.example/blah`   ->   which points to /blah.php

This is all you need:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found 100% working Concept for me:

```
# Options is required by Many Hosting
Options +MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# For .php & .html URL's:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Use this code in Root of your website .htaccess file like :

offline - wamp\www\YourWebDir

online - public_html/

> If it doesn't work correct, then change the settings of your Wamp
>   Server: 1) Left click WAMP icon 2) Apache 3) Apache Modules 4) Left
>   click rewrite_module

Comment: You can't have two `RewriteRule`s with the tag `L` next to each other. `[L]` tells `mod_rewrite` that it's the last rule for the specified `RewriteCond`.

Comment: It's the `Options +MultiViews` that makes this work (the rest of the directives can be removed)! But this now means that _any_ URL can be called without the extension (including all your images, CSS, JS, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that I used to hide the **`.php`** extension from the filename:

```
## hide .php extension
# To redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**Note: `R=301` is for permanent redirect and is recommended to use for SEO purpose. However if one wants just a temporary redirect replace it with just `R`**

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: In case you have extension other than .php (e.g. .txt) than this answer will help.

Answer (score 1):

If your URL in PHP like `http://yourdomain.example/demo.php` than comes like
`http://yourdomain.example/demo`

This is all you need:

```
create file .htaccess
```

---

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It worked for `http://example.com/myfile`  but it didn't work to `http://example.com/myfolder/` (index file). Can you help me make it work for the index file?

Comment: I think you should try above @starkeen answer URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30566026/3786343

Answer (score 1):

### For AWS Hosted (Ubuntu related servers) sites

**STEP 1 :** You need to edit the apache2 config file located in
`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**STEP 2 :** You have to edit the line that look like that:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
  Option Indexes FollowSymbLinks
  AllowOverride None    <-------- FOCUS ON THIS
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

You need to replace the `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride All`, then you need to enable rewrite mode in apache2 in the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**STEP 3 :** Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**STEP 4 :** Then You can Edit `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"   
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not work. An explanation would be helpful if it did though.

Comment: Does not work ..