# basic linking question

Tags: php, html

I've always added the file extension to a link "contact.php" is there anything wrong with excluding it and simply having `<a href="contact">`? seems to work fine, as Im having a lot of trouble with .htaccess removing the file extensions.
thx

Answer (score 1):

If this works, then probably thanks to [Apache's content negotiation / MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html). A proper set of mod_rewrite rules would be more reliable because it doesn't rely on `Options +MultiViews` being activated on the server, but if it works on the server it will be running on in the long term, it should be fine.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite) is an answer that should point you in the right direction if you still want to use mod_rewrite.

Comment: @Pekka I saw that link earlier, unfortunately, it doesn't remove extensions in the url for me. I also have some different requirements see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: @Dirty Gumbo's example in the linked question should work fine. I'll post an answer

Comment: @Dirty ah, no, there are some pitfalls that I would have to research myself, can't do that right now, sorry. I'll post what I can come up with off the top of my head.

Comment: actually when I put it on a server where the files were in the root, it works fine. when I put it in a test directory on a server it was going to the root directory and of course coming up with a 404. 2 questions if you have time 1. I'm doing some PHP link checking to add a class "current" in the nav include file, can i strip .php off the extension here <li <?php if (strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php')) echo 'class="current"';?>><a href="/index.php" target="_self" title="Home">home</a></li> and it will be ok? also how do I exclude one page, I have a session appended url to make sure they

Comment: download the software from only from the contact page

Comment: @Dirty I posted what I can tell you right now. As I said, you can strip the extension off if it works. Seeing as this is so difficult to do in .htaccess, maybe relying on the `MultiViews` option is a good idea for the moment