# Hiding the .html in a URL

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

How do I hide the .html ending on webpages?

I would like this:

http://www.exmaple.com/lorem.html

to look like this:

http://www.example.com/lorem/

I know that it would be possible to do by making a folder with an index page inside, but is there any way to tell the server to render '.html' as '/' ?

Comment: Please see [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the possibilities of [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/htaccess.html) if you have an apache webserver.

Answer (score 0):

for apache servers with mod_rewrite enabled add a .htaccess file into the root public html folder with the folowing content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^lorem/?$  lorem.html
```

this one will make the content from *example.com/lorem.html* available on *example.com/lorem/*

if you want to make a general rule for all .html files named with characters from A-Z, a-z, 0-9, you would make it as folows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  $1.html
```

this one will make the content from example.com/anyfile.html available at example.com/anyfile/ if anyfile contains the following characters: A-Z, a-z, 0-9

you may want to go deeper, so I'd suggest you to read this [cheetsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2.png).