# Simple mod_rewrite hide extension

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to hide extensions of my pages so that:

- `/page`
- `/page/`
- `/page.html`

All redirect to `page.html`.

This thread has a solution that almost works: [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

But when using `/page/`, it takes in consideration the trailing slash as a folder indicator, and as such all links and relative paths in this HTML file go to, say `/page/style.css`, instead of `/style.css`.

Here's my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: If you vote to close due to a duplicate, please forward me to a duplicate. Or to an evident Google result. I haven't found any.

Answer (score 0):

I wpould add an global variable $URL_ROOT to your php or other language and make all relative links to absolute links with it...

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need mod_rewrite for this, you can instead use [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) with [multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options).

Multiviews can be enabled by adding the following to your config or htaccess file.

`Options +MultiViews`

With the option enabled
`example.com/filename` will resolve to `example.com/filename.html` (without .html in the address bar).