# Webpages without a file extension

Tags: url, web, file-extension

I can see on that website that the url is `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`.
There is no file extension after that, and if the *ask* was a folder and inside that an index.aspx, for example, it would appear like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/`.
How do they do that? How do they make the extension disappear?
Thanks, Phantom

Comment: and what you ask is?

Comment: I ask how do they do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide the .html extension with Apache mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992183/how-to-hide-the-html-extension-with-apache-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How do they do that? How do they make the extension disappear?

The extension doesn't disappear, but there's simply no extension. In a quite recent (say 15 years) web programming world, a web application is no longer a bunch of actual directories of actual files. Web applications now have many different architectures and apply many patterns. Web server can also provide such a feature through URL rewriting extension. Both are usually combined as well.

The most common pattern that implements this is [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). The idea is that ALL requests goes to a single point of entrance. This entry point can then decide which code to execute to generate output. In most MVC frameworks, the URI after front controller name (usually index.php) is used to determine which controller class and controller method to call, though these days they're usually configurable.

In the example of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, one possible scheme is:

1. Web server rewrites the URL to `http://stackoverflow.com/index.php/questions/ask`
2. index.php as front controller then analyze the URI segments after its name, which is `/questions/ask`
3. It then contructs an instance of class `questions` and call its `ask` method
4. The method generates output that is then send back as response of the request

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand this topic now, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They are employing something called rewrite rules, probably in an .htaccess file in the web root of the site. They have added something like this to their .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine

RewriteRule    ^ask/?$   questions.php?questionID={1}    [NC,L]

Comment: Can you explain what the rewrite rule is saying?