# .htaccess: Remove .html and add a trailing slash

Tags: html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess file is:

```html
## Go Daddy servers need the Options -MultiViews code below
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.html
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.html [L]

# Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

But when I visit a page, it says "The requested URL /somepage/ was not found on this server." How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Remove .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This rule removes html extension from files and adds a tralling slash at the end of the file name.

Tested on Apache 2.4

Comment: Hmm, it seems to remove the CSS and assets from a page now.

Comment: If css  is the problem,then in head of your document add this **<base href="/">**

Comment: No, you should put **<base href="/">** in head section of your page, inbetween <head> and </head> tags, not in htaccess,

Comment: Is there any way to fix this CSS issue using the .htaccess file? The program I use to edit my site overrides all the manual changes I make to the HTML.

Comment: see my answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Answer (score 0):

```
# externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file and remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(?:html?|php)/?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=301,L,NE]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# internally add php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# internally add html extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

It works me for assets like css and js. Also work for trailing slash.