# Better to use - or / in a url

Tags: php, html

So I've just started using rewrite rules on my website and I've come across an unexpected problem.

I was changing links from

`http://localhost:8888/study.php?deckid=1101&studymethod=colorcoded&decksetting=deck`
to
`http://localhost:8888/study/1101/colorcoded/deck`

Which broke a lot of my links.
So I changed it to this

`http://localhost:8888/study-1101-colorcoded-deck`

Is this bad practice? Or perhaps in my original file I should just fix the links to where they pull from `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Here's my current rewrite code:

```
RewriteRule ^study/([0-9]+)/(.*)/(.*)$ study.php?deckid=$1&studymethod=$2&decksetting=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^study-([0-9]+)-(.*)-(.*)$ study.php?deckid=$1&studymethod=$2&decksetting=$3 [NC,L]
```

Currently the issue is:
When using the slashes version, my links (`<img src="../../img/picture.png">`)
are trying to pull links from `studymethod` instead of the root folder.

Basically, is it better to update all links with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` or just use dashes(-) instead.
Or does it not really matter as long as it works?

Comment: Where is your htaccess located? in root or subfolder?

Comment: @Starkeen My htaccess file is located in the root folder

Comment: Try adding a <base href="/"> inbetween <head> and </head> of your html document, this will correct the URI base of header

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Answer (score 0):

Both obviously work.

Generally though, you use `/` to separate actions from the item you're talking about, like `/read/101-psychology` or `/title/70143844`. If you have nested actions, you'll have more than one slash: `/admin/update/113242`.

Ultimately though it's up to you.

In your particular case, I'd use something like `/study/deck/1101?method=colorcoded` or something similar. Your action is studying a deck, and the item is 1101. Anything else is just parameters. In fact I wouldn't even store them as part of the query string, I'd put them in the session object (`/study/deck/1101`).

Comment: Is there a reason you'd prefer putting them in a session object? Less clutter/cleaner?

Comment: Yeah. And sharing the link to a page with someone shouldn't force them to use your view settings. They're personal to each person, so session/cookies/db.