# Pretty URL htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below url that I want to prettify. Any help appreciated.

From;

```
http://www.example.co.uk/search-menu?r_id=1&name=testname
```

To

```
http://www.abklab.co.uk/search-menu/1/testname
```

I have tried below but getting Internal Server Error

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (WEB)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+search-menu(?:\.php)?\?r_id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search-menu/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (WEB)
RewriteRule ^search-menu/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ search-menu.php?r_id=$1&name=%2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

FYI: Below rule removes .php extension site wide;

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?Page=$1&Section=$2 - the regex may not be 100% correct it will give you an idea

Comment: @moh.ABK your .htaccess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search-menu\?r_id=([^&]+)&name=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^search-menu/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ search-menu.php?r_id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: this gets me to the page but nothing is loaded eg css, js etc

Comment: You need to add a **<base href="/">** inbetween <head> and </head> of your webpage to correct the uri base of your header, so that js and css can work.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Answer (score 0):

Found something for you - the wizard will help you make your URL perfect
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your .htaccess file. It will take the variables and make is nice and pretty:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /search-menu?r_id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

Keep in mind this is basic and you will need to modify it to your addresses but it is just to give you the idea of what you need to do.