# how to rewrite url having multiple parameter and single parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i want to rewrite url for user ie. yourwebsite.com/profile.php?user=myname
and my code for rewrite is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

above code working great
but now i want to a specific file to rewrite ie.
yourwebsite.com/offer.php?oid=AA4&offid=1 to yourwebsite.com/offer/AA4/1

and my code for rewrite is

```
RewriteRule ^offer/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ offer.php?oid=$1&offid=$2 [L,NC]
```

but i am not getting expected result as it not show any css and some time shows

error 404 page. any help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following base tag to head section of your webpage :

```
<base href="/">
```

This will correct the header uri base for your relative links, css and js.

Comment: Related :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992