# htaccess SEF URL rewriting not working with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Please I'm facing some challenges with my URL rewriting.

I'm trying to rewrite:

```
domian.com?v=subj to domian.com/subj
```

and 
    domian.com?v=subj&id=3 to domian.com/subj/id

So users can directly access a clean URL.

Here's what I tried that wasn't working:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index.php/?$ $1? [NC]
```

I also tried this too:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9])$ http://domain.com/$1/$2 [NC]
```

Both were not working. Please I need some clarification on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following 2 rules to redirect query strings to SEF format.

```
RewriteEngine on

#--Redirect "?v=foo&id=bar" to "/foo/bar"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?v=([^&]+)&id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NC,L,R]
#--Rewrite "/foo/bar" to "?v=foo&id=bar"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Starkeen, that worked. Here's what i'm trying to do now: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?v=([^&]+)&id=([^&\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [NC,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?v=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [NC,R] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1 [NC,QSA]  i have multiple links i need to write rules for, but i couldn't get this to work. Do i use the same rule?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i was able to fix it. This works:     RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ ?v=$1  [QSA]   for rewriting urls like:  domain.com/?v=foo to domain.com/foo   But after adding this:                                        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?v=$1&id=$2&n=$3 [NC,QSA]        It wasn't working again, this was what i was trying to achieve:   domain.com/?v=foo&id=21&n=blog_post_name rewrite to domain.com/foo/blog_post_name to hide the id part for this single rule. Thanks Starkeen, also absolute urls for images are not loading.

Comment: @SamsonAde 


See this post if youR images,css and js are not working on rewritten urls :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: Thanks so much @starkeen. It works perfect now. I did some other research and found that, before each line of the rewrite rule, the css and other media files couldn't be loaded. I had to place RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f before each line of the rewrite rule code. Now it loads my css, js, and other media files. Thanks. :-)