# htaccess Multiple URL Variable clean URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Ok i've tried multiple versions of code on my .htaccess file and I still can't get it to work properly... I don't know if I'm putting it in the wrong folder or what is going on but, here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

**This is my code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rentals/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?zipcode=([^\s&]+)&location=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?zipcode=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**Here is another version that I've tried**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rentals/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?zipcode=([a-z0-9]+)&location=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?zipcode=$1&location=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish... a URL that looks like this:
*example.com/rentals/32746/florida*

The "32746" and the "florida" come from a form on the index page of the site and then it gets passed over to the "rentals" folder through the URL.

The .htaccess code sorta works whereas it spits out a URL like this:
http://www.example.com/rentals/12345/arkansas?zipcode=12345&location=arkansas

But do you see the extra on the tail end? It's as if it's duplicating the results in the URL.

I currently have the .htaccess file in my "*rentals*" folder should it be in the root folder?

---

**UPDATED VERSION**

For those who were running into the same problem as myself... here is the actual code I ended up going with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rentals/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?zipcode=([^\s&]+)&location=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?zipcode=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a **?** to the end of the target path in your first Rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rentals/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+index\.php\?zipcode=([a-z0-9]+)&location=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?zipcode=$1&location=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

As it descards the orignal query strings from the destination.

Clear your browser's cache before testing this.

Comment: it now just goes to _example.com/rentals/index.php?zipcode=32827&location=florida_ i copied the code you provided, replaced my code in the .htaccess file then uploaded it to the **/rentals/** folder and tested it from Firefox (whereas chrome was the original browser) any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @Antivinegar 
Yes, the problem is that , The RewriteCond is trying to match /index.php of the Root folder. Remove **^[A-Z]{3,}\s+** from the cond.

Comment: thanks for the help... it worked to switch the URL into the format I wanted however when the URL is displayed its as if none of the CSS is intact and the page is displayed as if the CSS is broken when I know it's not whereas the page worked before implementing the .htaccess changes

Comment: @Antivinegar To fix css, js and other relative links, You need to add a base tag to the head section of your webpage **<base href="/">** or use a absolute path eg **<link rel="/style.css"** rather then **<link rel="style.css"**

Comment: even that didn't work... i tried to direct link them too & that still didn't work.  See I only created one folder named "rentals" & the "Zipcode" & "location" were just inputs from a form that is carried over to "/rentals/index.php"  I've also tried this code & it works perfect... except that the "location" doesn't pass in the URL `RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rentals/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?zipcode=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?zipcode=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: @Antivinegar I know what you mean. but The the modified  version of your code is accepting and passing just 1 perameter. Is css working on this?

Comment: yes the css appears to be functioning fine... but, the js files don't seem to be working. Even when I direct path them. I've also tried this `RedirectMatch permanent ^/rentals/((css|js)/.*)  /$1`

Comment: @Antivinegar are the css and js inside rental folder?

Comment: no they are in the root folder... I haven't tried to move the to the "rentals" folder.

Comment: I think you need to remove the **RedirectMatch** because it is conflicting with css and js. Also clear the browser's cache. **<base href="/">** is all you need to fix the css and js. Let me know if it doesnt solve.

Comment: @antivinegar For more info about how to fix css and js on rewritten url, please read
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992