# htaccess URL rewrites with multiple GET variables and relative URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

In `.htaccess`, I have put a simple `RewriteRule` with two `GET` variables in the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^myurl/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) /folder_1/myfile.php?a=$1&b=$2
```

Inside `folder_1`, there are two files: `myfile.php` and `myCSS.css`

In `myfile.php`, when I am having to refer to `myCSS.css`, I am having to do:

```
<link href="../../folder_1/myCSS.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `../../` is needed to get past the two `GET` variables set above.

But surely, there must be a better way, as I should be able to add more `GET` variables and not having to change the relative URL to the CSS each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this,you can add the following base tag to the head of your document :

```
<base href="http://example.com/">
```

For more info,see this post [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)