# how can I allow an optional backslash on urls with .htaccess file and not let browsers think I am accessing a subfolder?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewritting my php pages with .htaccess file and when I allow an optional backslash ("/"), the pages are not loaded propely when I include the backslash in the urls. I know that one solution to the problem is to use absolute urls instead of relative urls so that my css and javascript files can be loaded properly. I want another way to solve this, maybe with .htaccess file or something else. I want to use relative urls in my projects.

Comment: / is a slash, not backslash

Comment: To fix the relative css ,js and images, you can simply add the following base tag to the head section of your webpage : **<base href="/">** See this post for more info  :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Answer (score 1):

To be sure i understand what you want. You want this files to redirect like this

```
/example -> example.php
/example/ -> example.php
```

If that is the case, you can use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ $1.php
```

It can be translated to this:

```
if requested_file is no directory,
if requested_file does not exist,
then print me the contents of the request_file with a php extension at the end :D 
otherwise just print me whats inside the request_file
```