# Skip apache rewrite for css and js

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a problem when trying to set a rewrite on apache.

I want that every subdomain, excluded real folders, are redirected to index.php?cat=$subdomain.

That's work well but the folders css, images and js which exists are redirected too and I get 404.

Here my .htdocs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a URL which gets redirected but should not.

Comment: Hi,  for example if I go to http://www.example.com/category1/ it is redirected to index.php?cat=category1 but I get 404 on images as they're searched in http://www.example.com/category1/images/1.jpg rather than http://www.example.com/images/1.jpg     Thanks

Comment: So http://example.com/images/1.jpg returns a 404 when called in the browser? Or is the actual URL requested being http://example.com/category1/images/1.jpg? If the second is true, then maybe you could use absolute URLs for your images in your HTML, like `src="/images/1.jpg"` instead of `src="images/1.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a base tag to the head of your document :

```
<base href="/">
```

This will correct the uri base for your images and js on a rewritten url.

For more info ,Read this post [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)