# htaccess ignore/remove trailing slash from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website I have a page in `examle.com/dir1/di2/index.php`, and if I type `examle.com/dir1/di2/index.php/` (with slash in the end), it show me the website without working css file. I want that when the user enter to `examle.com/dir1/di2/index.php/`, or any other addess in the website, to ignore the slash in the url.

Comment: If you have any rewrite rule in your current .htaccess, it's better to post here. We can suggest better rules or modify that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)