# Htaccess rewrite url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am currently rewriting urls on my website and I bumped into a problem. In the example below I rewrite /?page=somepage to something prettier. domain.com/page

```
RewriteRule ^aboutus$  /index.php?page=about [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^services$  /index.php?page=services [NC,L]
```

This works perfectly, but when I want to display domain.com/category/page it messes up the way the css, js and images are loaded.

```
RewriteRule ^partners/cloudflare$  /index.php?page=cloudflare [NC,L]
```

This works but on that page all the assets are loaded like this: domain.com/partners/assets/...
How can I modify that rule to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed