# htaccess hide subfolder in all pages

Tags: .htaccess, hide, subdirectory

I found similar topics, but not an answer working for me.

My htaccess is actually :

```
RewriteEngine on


# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?publigraphix\.com$
RewriteRule !^Jomla_344french/ /Jomla_344french%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]/Jomla_344french%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

With this, I can hide the subfolder in the url of my homepage, but it appears again by opening any page of my website.

How can I hide the subfolder in the url on all pages ?

Thank You for help, this is my first post.
Greetings,

Susanne

Thanks for Your help. Now my htaccess is like this : 
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?publigraphix.com$ 
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Jomla_344french/(.*)\sHTTP [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?publigraphix.com$ 
    RewriteRule !^Jomla_344french /Jomla_344french%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L]

For the homepage, this works fine, but in the subpages, the url displays /index.php/ with an 404 error (for example url shows : publigraphix.com/index.php/tampons instead of publigraphix.com/tampons ...) Do You have an idea?

Comment: what url are you going to?

Comment: @starkeen www.publigraphix.com should open http://publigraphix.com/Jomla_344french/index.php

Comment: I want to hide the subfolder /Jomla_344french in all pages on that website but actually it is only hidden on the homepage

Answer (score 0):

To hide the subfolder ,you can use

```
RewriteEngine on


# remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?publigraphix\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Jomla_344french/(?:index\.php/)?(.*)\sHTTP [NC]

RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NE,L,R]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?publigraphix\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!Jomla_344french).*) /Jomla_344french/index.php/$1  [NC,L]
```

Comment: @Susanne52 sorry there was a small typo in the last rule, Try the edited code now

Comment: hm, still not working, sorry. Could You look at [link](http://www.publigraphix.com) and then open any of the pages ? You will see /index.php in the url

Comment: @Susanne52 this is not working because of the **index.php** Do you want to remove it?

Comment: Yes, please. Can You do that ?

Comment: Have a look at the site now ... homepage is ok, but when You clic on any page, the homepage remains !

Comment: I put the old htacces online, just to keep the website working for the week-end. Your last code hacks layout of the website. Thanks for Your help, I will retry monday (have 3 kids ...)

Comment: Good morning ! So I put Your file online again in order to show You the broken layout. Do You have an idea ? I saw in other threads some hints about adding a <base href="/" /> but I don't know where to place it and I get an 500 error page if I place it under RewriteEngine on.

Comment: Very good morning @susanne52 Yes thats true **<base href="/">** can solve the layout on rewritten url. Add base tag to the head section of your webpage, inbetween **<head></head>**

Comment: @Susanne52 For mor info, read my answer on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Comment: I don't understand much, sorry. Can You see on my homepage which file I need to modify ? I have several css files (it's a joomla site).