# not rewrite css or js or image files htaccess

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url like this:

> mysite.com/1/everything

and I want to rewrite it and only get the number in the url (e.g. 1 above). For that, I have written a `htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule for root pages
RewriteRule (^\d+\/?([\x00-\x7F]|[^\x00-\x7F])+\/?$) index-continue.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But all of my `css` files and image files and js files get rewritten! How can I solve this problem? This causes all the file rewrites on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess file should only keep the following thing, it will allow your js and css to open directly with the path root/css/file.css and root/js/file.js

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^style/([^/.]+)?$ style/$1
RewriteRule ^js/([^/.]+)?$ js/$1
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ index-continue.php?id=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Comment: [^/.]+ denies / and . in string! my css files are in style/app.css path, so it gets 404 error, (i have changed css into style but 404 not resolved)

Comment: I have edited the answer, check it if its working or not?

Comment: i myself have resolve it , thanks alot my dear. the result is:

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)?$ index-continue.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/styles/(.+)?$ /mysite/styles/$2 [NC,L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

To fix the css and js path on rewritten urls, you need to add the following base tag to the head section of your webpage :

```
<base href="/">
```

Related :

[Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)