# can not load css and js after htaccess redirect url in php

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am redirect my url using htaccess and i use this code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mobile?$ index.php
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ product.php?c=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L]

and also add this code in product.php 
<head> <base href="http://localhost/asp/" /> </head>
```

That code in product.php file. I redirect successfully but can not load css and js in proper way. Can any one suggest to me how can i load css and js on product.php page.I can load image successfully but page design is not working correctly.I have search a lot of but not get proper answer please any one can provide the way or code which is helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: @starkeen this not working for me can you give any suggestion

Comment: Use an absolute path for your css,js and images ,ex **/style.css** instead of **style.css**

Comment: @starkeen i have done this but i don't know  why is not working

Comment: How are your css,js and images loading? could you view the source of your webpage?

Comment: imges is loading but js and css is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the default bahavior of base is to replace the url(adress) before the relative adress.
example:

`<base href="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/" target="_blank">`

The browser will look for the image "html5.png" at "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/html5.gif".

Hope it help you !

Answer (score 0):

Create a main folder then putt all the files in folder like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8NDT.png) ...

Comment: can you use include method?