# htaccess -> Rewriting a request

Tags: .htaccess, post, url-rewriting

I'm going to try and make this as simple as possible, I have a POST form that sends information called $searchid, I want to redirect it to look like a directory

I want to take the following information: (Server, folder, file, post)

> localhost/shorts/profile.php?searchid=12345

And I want to make it look like (Server, fakefolder(id), fakefolder(post))

> localhost/id/12345/

Also, is there A way to incorporate the sitename, as all the htaccess ive seen before hasnt had it and it's been showing the entire path from C drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In htaccess in the root :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^id/([0-9]+)/?$ /sports/profile.php?searchid=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite

- /id/numbers

to

- /sports/profile.php?searchid=numbers

and allow you to access the page `/sports/profile.php?searchid=numbers` using the clean url `/id/numbers` .

Comment: That worked, thanks! Although it seems to have re-written the path to the CSS and now it's not working, any way I can counter the CSS and exclude it?

Comment: @SheaLavington 


To fix css , js and relative resources, use the following base tag in head section of your webpage `<base href="/">` 

Read this post for more info :

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working