# Rewrite &sub=value to /value .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working with a pagination system on a school project website, but the problem is we only learn PHP, HTML5, CSS3 and graphical design stuff, no .htaccess coding.

My pagination system is based on the $_GET function. Index.php?pagina=value gets overwritten by .htaccess to /value. But I want to add an extra &get layer to my pages.

How do I do this with .htaccess so I can get /value/value (index.php?value&sub=value)?

Below you can find my current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [L,NC]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass query strings to the target url, you can use the QSA (Query String Append) flag for that. QSA flag  combines new and old query string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This will rewrite :

- /value/?querystrin

to

- index.php?pagina=$1&querystring

EDIT  :

To rewrite

- /index.php?pagina=value&sub=value

to

- /value/value

You can use these rules :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?pagina=([^&]+)&sub=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pagina=$1&sub=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: That sadly didnt work. I need to get index.php?pagina=value&sub=value to be rewritten to /value/value. The code I already have only works for ?pagina=value into /value :(

Comment: @Going4quests try the new rule

Comment: That one works, but when going to /value/value no css or images load. :s

EDIT: Seems to work. Mb. I was refering everything with css/style.css, images/image.jpg.. Added / to each url and it works!

Comment: @Going4quests To fix css, js ,images and othere relative resources you need a add the following base tag in head section of your webpage `<base href="/">`
 read this thread for more info :



 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!