# IIS URL Rewrite CSS, JS NOT Loading

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, iis, web-config

i have following structure in my php web project which i am trying to host on IIS 10 express.

- controllers
- inc
- sass
- web

  - css
  - js
  - index.php
- web.config

all my URLs should rewrite to url="./web/index.php"
therefore i wrote following web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".?" ignoreCase="true" />
                 <conditions>
                     <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                 </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./web/index.php" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Now i have the problem that css, js,... all relative resources are not working anymore. Any idea what i did wrong?

KR Manuel

Comment: See this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: did not work for me