# Why use base href for .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, radix

here is my `.htaccess` code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-([^/]+)-([^/]+)/?.html$ movies.php?m=$3&id=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

here in movies.php page i need to use `<base href="/">` why?
is here any process to use same `.htaccess` but not use `<base href="/">`
? or can i do same work with any other process? PLease help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `<base href>` you can use a PHP variable for the base path:

```
<?php
$base = dirname(getenv('SCRIPT_NAME')); // May not work depending on the server config :/
?>
```

This allows you to use relative URLs in your HTML, but make consistent URLs where needed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base?>/theme.css">
```

Or simply add a forward slash if your stylesheet (as per example) is to be at the root of your website:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/theme.css">
```