# URL rewriting with .htaccess and relative paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a small problem with rewriting urls. I have this really simple rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(home|apps|news|research|contribute)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

However, whenever I call my website like this, e.g. website.net/home/ it correctly rewrites the rule and shows the corresponding page but also messes up the css and images since it rewrites the urls for them since they are relative paths in the code.
Is there any easy way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is the URL you're trying to rewrite? It's easier to understand what you want to achieve that way.

Comment: I've read 5 times and don't understand, what your problem actually is. Give some example.

Comment: the problem is that it actually also rewrites the url for the links to the stylesheets and images which makes them not load

Comment: It does not look so. Sure they are rewritten? They are relative to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the rewritten urls. when the url is  **example.com/home/** apache thinks **/home/** is a directory and appends **/home/** in front of all relative urls.

To solve this, You can add the following base tag in head section of your webpage :

```
<base href="/">
```

Related : [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like the perfect solution if it works. I'm gonna try that out as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Add this following line in your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|css|js|inc\.php)$ -[L]
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work although it made me realize there might be a way to exclude certain files via a condition?

Comment: Either you should use absolute paths for your files or yes you can make exception for a certain types of files.