# Image URL is not resolving correctly when viewed in controller template

Tags: php, image, symfony

I have the following Symfony 5 based PHP web application structure:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── bin
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
├── config
├── migrations
├── phpunit.xml.dist
├── public
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── 3e28ae7b9f72cb1958e532161709f559.jpg
│   │   ├── f16b8e3277415e2783d076177aee8f7e.jpg
│   │   └── fe0920ac3d2b89f1cd4d787cedc3daf4.jpg
│   └── index.php
├── src
│   ├── Controller
│   │   └── CatController.php
├── symfony.lock
├── templates
├── tests
├── translations
├── var
└── vendor
```

`CatController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Cat;
use App\Repository\CatRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * @Route("/cat")
 */
class CatController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="cat_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Cat $cat): Response
    {
        return $this->render('cat/show.html.twig', [
            'cat' => $cat,
        ]);
    }
}
```

`Cat.php` (Entity):

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CatRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CatRepository::class)
 */
class Cat
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $image;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

`cat/show.html.twig`:

```
{{ cat.image }}

<img src="{{ cat.image }}"/ >
```

This template produces HTML, which looks correct:

```
images/3e28ae7b9f72cb1958e532161709f559.jpg
    
<img src="images/3e28ae7b9f72cb1958e532161709f559.jpg">
```

But the image does not actually render, and when I right click on where the image should be and select 'Open in new tab'.

A new tab opens and the URL is set to:

http://localhost:8000/cat/images/3e28ae7b9f72cb1958e532161709f559.jpg

Is there a way to prevent `/cat` prefix on the rendered URL? Which is preventing the image url from resolving correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting with .htaccess and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645424/url-rewriting-with-htaccess-and-relative-paths)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset(cat.image)) }}"/ >
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#linking-to-css-javascript-and-image-assets

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was:

```
<img src="../{{ house.image }}"/ >
```

to access the parent directory and append the image url.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
<img src="/{{ cat.image }}"/ >
```

In this way you don't have to change it if you decide to move to another folder ...