# redirect url with .htaccess image and css not loading

Tags: php, jquery, css, .htaccess

I have in problem in loading CSS, JS and image etc on the page. My code is this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Prevent loops
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*  %1/index.php?cat_id=%2&subcat_id=%2&product_id=%2 [L]
```

When I access the URLs below, CSS, etc loads fine:

> http:// localhost/test/
>   http:// localhost/test/category/

After I access this URL, CSS, JS and images are not working.

> http:// localhost/test/category/subcategory/productname

Comment: Put your images, js & css files on the root directory

Comment: Use a path to your CSS which is relative to the root directory of the site, not the current folder.

Comment: how i mean where in root directory

Comment: its working with this url http:// localhost/test/
http:// localhost/test/category/

Comment: usually i make a config file, name: config.php  and i set directory  address in that file. easy for edit. make sure you have same directory in both

Comment: but after this http:// localhost/test/category/subcategory/productname not working

Comment: i dident understand what to do with config.php

Comment: Related : [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: i was not getting understand please edit my code plz

Comment: Your files are not redirecting from the root as base, but instead relative to it's own location.

Comment: no solution for this here

Comment: no one have solution for my query