# htaccess url rewrite 400 bad request

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I added the below to htaccess. The url looks fine now though I started getting 400 Bad request whenever i go to a product page - www.link.com/product/123/foo

i used the below first rule to redirect from "/product.php\?product_id=123&product_name=foo" to "/product/123/foo"

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?product_id=([^&]+)&product_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /product/%1/%2? [NE,L,R]
```

and then the 2nd rule to internally map "/product/123/foo" to "/product.php\?product_id=123&product_name=foo"

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)/(.+)/?$  product.php?product_id=$1&product_name=$2   [B,NC,L]
```

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: @starkeen yes tried from an incognito tab as well, please help me in this you wrote this originally

Comment: would you post the uri that caused 400 error?

Comment: @starkeen can you help ?

Comment: Please post the full uri ,you can change your sitename to example.com

Comment: @starkeen any product page 
example.com/product/91/50%-ON-Clothe,-For-Summer
example.com/product/71/50%-ON-35-Clipse-($20-instead-of-$40)

Comment: Your rule is ok. Problem is with the uri. your uri contains reserved url characters such as **%** , **$** that is why it doesnt work when you remove the B flag, b flag converts those chars to hex ,and NE flag converts hex to english chars eg  %30 to  ;.

Comment: @starkeen can you tell me how it should all be ? i removed the B flag from the second rule and removed the NE flag from the first rule, it worked but page loads as if theres not css and js loading

Comment: This url http://example.com/product/144/50%25-ON-Clothe%2c-For-summer is working fine for me. You cant avoid the precent encoding if there are reserved chars in the uri

Comment: Read this post for your css and js issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working/31241992#31241992

Comment: @starkeen ok that should work then when i change the base uri, but how can i not show the 25 after % and %2c from the url ?

Comment: You cant avoid %25 unless you remove **%** completly from the orignal uri.

Comment: @starkeen it worked by removing the NE flag from the first rule and keeping the B flag in the second rule, what do you think ?