# Redirect to dynamic relative paths with .htaccess and php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I did that when I enter this url `www.foo.it/items/first`
the page is redirected to `www.foo.it/index.php`
and it is working properly.
The problem is that the page I linked a picture with a relative path `src = "img/brand1.png"` and doing the redirection considers the current path is not `"/"` but `"/items/"` and then can not find the image.
I am not an expert, can you tell me how can I solve my problem?
This is my redirect:

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working