# mod_rewrite changes links in php response

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please can someone explain what is happening here? This .htaccess correctly redirects to that page in the root directory but all the links on the page now include a (non-existent) sub-directory "test" (though the html source doesn't)

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ /view_player.php?player=$1
```

ps the same thing happened before I put in the "RewriteBase /" and "/" before the view_player.php destination, they were included in my attempt to find out what is happening.

What do I need to do to stop this happening?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: Thanks, starkeen, that question had the answer to put   <base href="/"> in the page headers which solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your `RewriteRule`, you will see there is a section that says `^test/`. This is known as a `prefix` and you can use this to modify your URL and therefore improving the form of the rewritten URL and increasing its relevancy.

So for example, if I had a URL that read:

`www.exmaple.com/common-errors/an-error`

I might what to include a `prefix` called errors, and therefore rewriting it to:

`www.example.com/errors/common-errors/an-error`

Comment: I do not understand your answer. The prefix matches the pattern mysite.com/test/600 which is what I want but it does not appear in the replacement,