# When i point my browser to website site.com/index.php/"non-existent-dir" shows index.php the page with no css

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes


RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[no css styles applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hpAK.jpg)

I dont want the page to show at all... is it not supposed to show te 404 page i configured?

index.php/ is not a directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: no, that's not the problem...

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not using absolute path for your style/image href and src.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/design/style.css"/>
<img src="/design/mylogo.php"/>
```

As you can see I have added / in front of a path, so I am pointing browser to search for a file in a root location. When you are on url   http://example.com/index.php/somename browser is trying to find css/images on this location   http://example.com/index.php/somename/design/style.css or http://example.com/index.php/somenamde/design/mylogo.png.

Comment: I dont want the page to show at all... is it not supposed to show te 404 page i configured?

Comment: when i use absolute paths images are not shown on home page