# htaccess rewrite rule displaying page without css

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem with rewriting url using a .htaccess file.
In my case it either doesn't work or redirects me to a page without css.
I have set 3 rules for testing. Here they are:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index/women/?$ index-women.php [NC] 
RewriteRule ^index/men/?$ index-men.php [NC] 
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 79.75.60.8

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

I denied access from any ip address beside my own.

First of all, when I enter my page then it automatically shows the page name with extension (i.e www.example.com/index.php). I need to change url manually to www.example.com/index. When I do that however a page without any styling is displayed.

How do I redirect to pages with css included?
Also, how do I make sure that I don't have to correct the url manually each time?

PS. I've googled for some tutorials but does anyone know a good tutorial with all symbols/letters explained as well? Much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: I have another issue now, should I edit this questions or ask a new one?
It's still related to this htaccess file.