# URL Rewriting does not work using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the following URL

```
http://dramatainment.com/dramas.php?id=000020&channel=HUM%20TV
```

My goal is to achieve this URL

```
http://dramatainment.com/dramas/id/000020/channel/HUM-TV/
```

Here Is the code I am using in my .htaccess file which is placed in the same folder as my index.php and dramas.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule dramas/(.*)/(.*)/ dramas.php?id=$1&channel=$2
RewriteRule dramas/(.*)/(.*) dramas.php?id=$1&channel=$2
```

I got this code from a tutorial, it worked great for them in that tutorial. It works for me in the localhost, not online. What could be the problem? Why does it not work on live website?

Comment: Try to use `<base href="localhost/(path to projectdirectory)">` in your head section of dramas page.

Comment: Do I write localhost when working on the online server? Like
<base href="localhost/http://dramatainment.com/">

Comment: If it is live site then you can use domain of your site.

Comment: Just like this <base href="http://dramatainment.com/">  ?

Yes the site is live

Comment: Did that, no effect. Same results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: My question is 100% different. The URL rewriting does not work at all. The question you have mentioned in the link says CSS does not load but URL rewriting works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Well the `<base href="">` tag i suggested is for linking css file properly.

For your url try it like this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/id/([\d]+)/channel/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?id=$2&channel=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: ThankYou for your time. I tried the code you provided and then accessed the page using this URL 
http://dramatainment.com/dramas/id/000020/channel/hum-tv/

It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dramas/id/([^/]*)/channel/([^/]*)$ /dramas.php?id=$1&channel=$2 [L]`

Comment: Should I not write like this? for what i am trying to achieve?
^dramas/id/([^/]*)/channel/([^/]*)$ /dramas.php?id=$1&channel=$2 [L]

Comment: Anyways, tried both with and without dramas, nothing happened. Same results. 404 error. File not found on this server.