# How to include CSS/JS and other files with a PHP routing and .htaccess

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, routes

I'm trying to apply CSS on HTML with a PHP routing class but it doesn't work...

I want the *H1 red color style* to be included, here is the code...

> .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

> index.php

```
<?php
class R 
{
    private $r = [];
    function a($r, callable $c)
    {
        $this->r[$r] = $c;
    }

function e() {
    $p = $_GET['p'];
    $k = isset($this->r[$p]) ? $this->r[$p] : $this->r[''];
    $k();
}
}

$router = new R;

$router->a('/', function(){
    include "page/home.php";
});

$router->e();
?>
```

> home.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Colorized.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

> style.css

```
h1 {
color: red;
}
```

How can I make this work with *any* **CSS/JS** files which was added within the HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: Did the linked answer work for you?

Comment: It didn't solved my problem yet, I'm trying to understand what to change in my .htaccess file but unfortunately can't figure out how to get it done.

Comment: What happens when you visit your site? Does the routing work fine?

Comment: Yes. but, the CSS is not included with `<link>`, maybe I can hack it by including css as php into `<style>` but i'm looking for a proper solution...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your rule is rewriting css and js files back to index.php and that is why they arent loading. You need to exclude those file from the rule.

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^((?!\.js|\.css).*)$ /index.php?p=/$1 [L]
```

And to fix relative uris ,add the following in head section of you web page

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: I think it's not working, it redirects to the main parent directory so I've tried to add `RewriteBase /directory/` and got the "page not found" routing.