# Two directory URLs htaccess

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

whatever my URL, i want to direct to index.php. I specify what to do with the URL, on Angularjs. I can directing URLs like example.com/page to index.php, but i can't directing URLs like example.com/profiles/user1 to index.php with htaccess codes I found on the internet. My code is not working when there is a second slash in the URL. How can I solve this problem?

My htaccess codes;

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I thank you in advance for your helps

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: On console, directory looks as profile.php. It not find css and js files because of the directory looks wrong. Therefore no code and style is running in the page. Only html codes and non-working angularjs codes looks. @starkeen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: Teşekkür ederim, işe yaradı :) @starkeen

Comment: I didn't get that.....lol..

Comment: Sory, I mistakenly wrote in my own language :) Thank you, it worked :) @starkeen

Comment: Your welcome! Glad it worked out..cheers!