# Image not loading when using RewriteEngine?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have created a url shortener, I am using a rewrite rule however the images on my page are not loading when I have this turned on, and this is only a problem when I first load the page. If I remove the rule, load the page, and then turn the rule back on the images will stay however when I first open up my browser and load the page with the rule on then the images will not load. Can anyone help me out with this? Here is my code.

index.php

```
<?php
  include 'connect.php';

  if(isset($_GET['title'])) {
      $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM atomly_shortener WHERE id=?");
      $result->bind_param("s", $_GET['title']);
      $result->execute();

      $goto = $result->get_result()->fetch_array();
      $g = $goto[1];
      header("location: $g");
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit_url'])) {
    if(substr($_POST['submit_url'], 0, 7) != "http://") {
        $longurl= "http://".$_POST['long_url'];
    } else {
        $longurl=$_POST['long_url'];
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO atomly_shortener (long_url) VALUES ('$longurl')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, long_url FROM atomly_shortener WHERE long_url='$longurl'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
      // Set session variables
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if($result->num_rows > 0) {
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
          $long = $row["long_url"];
          $id = $row["id"];
          $shorturl = $id;
          $sql = "UPDATE atomly_shortener SET short_url = '$shorturl' WHERE long_url='$longurl'";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$shorturl');</script>";
                //echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('shorter').innerHTML = 'hello'; </script>";
            } else {
              echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
            }
      }
      else {
        echo "Unknown Error!";
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "Error shortening url, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>

<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container">
            <img id = "logo" src = "images/atomly_logo.png"></img>
            <form method="post" action="index.php">
                <fieldset class = "cf">
                    <input id = "url_long" type = "text" class = "shorten-input" placeholder = "Please enter your url..." name="long_url"></input>
                    <input id = "submit_" type = "submit" name = "submit_url" class = "action-btn" value = "SUBMIT"></input>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <div id ="shorter"><h1><?php if(isset($shorturl)){ echo "Short URL: localhost:81/atomly/".$shorturl; } ?></h1></div>
        </div>
    <body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The image that is not loading is on this line

```
<img id = "logo" src = "images/atomly_logo.png"></img>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your *.htaccess* file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff)$ index.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```