# Htaccess keep images and css

Tags: css, image, .htaccess, path

I have a folder structure like this:

- index.php
- css/style.css
- images/image.png
- .htaccess

in my htaccess I'd like to add some rules in order to create an URL that looks like: home/5/6 that goes to page: index.php?var1=5&var2=6

Doing home/5 to index.php?var1=5 works in the way I do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ $1 [NC,L]
```

However for 2 (or more) variables the css and images are no longer loading when adding this to my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)/(.*)$ $2 [NC,L]
```

in image and css tags I use relative paths only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: @starkeen it looks like it yes, however using a base href=/ all the file paths will start from the root while my working directory can be in an unknown subfolder / location

Answer (score 0):

Oke i found out by some help of others and here is my solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png||ttf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|woff2|ttf|woff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/assets/(.*)$ assets/$2 [NC,L]
```

By knowing that all of my stylesheets, images and other assets are located in subfolders inside the folder assets, I was able to split the rewritten path from the real path and then continue.

Thanks for the help though!