# images,js, css not loaded when using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

First what I want to note it for you is 
I use appserv.

I create the .htaccess file in direct file, so .htaccess file is in the folder /web.

All I want is use RewriteRule for all web links except (.css)-(.js)-(all types of images and .txt)-(and all files name).

I use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^content/([0-9]+)/$ content.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

but when I open this page as `web/content/2`, the css, js, images are not loaded.

I do not know what's the problem :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: Resolved bro thank you for your replaying, i just was forget to adding meta base in head.

Comment: Your welcome!! Glad to hear it worked out. You may mark your question as duplicate by clicking the blue box right bellow your question title. Thanks.