# Combo of RewriteCond & RewriteRule Fails (maybe because # character?)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to create a RewriteRule that only applies when uri begins with "promo".

Here's my try at the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} promo
RewriteRule promo/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /arrivals#archive?d=$1&n=$2&e=$3 [L]
```

Page loads but every file on the page (for example all of the scripts, css, etc. in head get rewritten too.

For example, `http://me.me/promo/57b90202e4b0ab3a09bfd396/0/058b2f7c8e4b0ce83572fa970.html`

will take`<script src=moment.min.js></script>` in head and rewrite it to `http://me.me/promo/57b90202e4b0ab3a09bfd396/0/moment.min.js` which throws a `GET` error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)