# Why not working the / correctly with .htaccess in php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I wrote this htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I use xampp and my menu structure for example: Home(/) and Contact(/contact), and the localhost/project/ is working i get the home page, but when i go to the localhost/project/contact, the contact page is ok but the Home menupoint url will be localhost not the localhost/project/. I think because of the xampp domain or because of my project is under the xampp/htdocs/project  or something like that...could anyone helps to me how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

html:

```
<a href="/">HOME</a>
<a href="contact">Contact</a>
```

Comment: You need to show some code. _Questions "why isn't this code working?" must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be because of your link setup within your HTML if you have `<a href="/">Home</a>` then it will go to localhost/ because it doesn't read from your htaccess. You will either need to update your href to `/project/home` or you will need to add a Redirect rule to your htaccess and redirect the root to /project/ which will solve your issue.

EDIT: Your contact is working because you don't have the forward slash at the beginning which makes it a relative link. If you placed a forward slash before contact then it would go to `localhost/contact` it's recommended to have an absolute path (forward slash at the beginning) and link to it like `<a href="/project/contact">Contact</a>` and `<a href="/project">Home</a>`

Comment: thanks for the help, i knew that something like that. Now i create a rule in the xampp/htdocs which is redirect everything to project/ :)