# .htaccess mod_rewrite doesnt work as I (think) i configured it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try using mod_rewrite but it doesn't seem to work, probally a stupid error on my side.

when i go to index.php?page=home i want to make the url cleaner, I get no error but it also doesn't work

this is in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^page/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Does it work  when you go to `example.com/page/something` ?

Comment: Kind of, the css and plugins arent loaded but I see the text. But whatever page I try it always go to the index.php and not the page. It did work before I tried .htaccess but the url was "dirty"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule you have in htaccess only changes new links to the old ones ie `/page/something` to `/index.php?page=something` . This doesnt handle your old  links.If you don't want your old links to be accessible you can redirect them to the new url format (cleaner version) using RewriteRule.

Add the following lines above your existing rules but bellow `RewriteEngine on`

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index.php\?page=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [L,R]
```

To fix the css issue see this post
[Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: thnx :D it worked for my .htaccess and my css issue. It's not 100% working (some paths are borky now) but I can figure the rest out myself