# URL rewriting messes with accessing file

Tags: php, html, url, url-rewriting

I just recently found out about url rewriting and i wanted to change my url from `search.php?s=keyword&p=pagenum` to `search/keyword/pagenum`. Therefor i created these rules in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule    ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   search.php?s=$1    [NC,L] 
RewriteRule    ^search/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    search.php?s=$1&p=$2   [NC,L]
```

The redirecting part works, i just noticed that my pictures on the search results are missing. This is my folder layout:

```
root/
---search.php
---images/
   ---{id}.jpg
```

in my search.php i access images like this: `<img src='images/" . $id . ".jpg'>`. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and if possible how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

err, try

> img src='../images/$id.jpg'>

or

> img src='/images/$id.jpg'>

Comment: already tried that and it doesn't work, it somehow has to know how many / there are in the url and calculate it accodringly