# .htaccess file preventing css from loading

Tags: css, .htaccess

I am new to .htaccess files and have been trying to do a few simple rewrites on my site. However this has caused an issue loading all of the other resources on the domain specifically my stylesheet.

My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ page.php?page_id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But then I get the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://example.com/beta/web/style.css".
```

I was trying to do a bit of research into this and read somewhere that using absolute file paths for my stylesheet would be better.

So instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="web/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>`

I put in `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/beta/web/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>`

However that just resulted in a different error:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/EUR/web/style.css/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: use `text/css` mime type?

Comment: @MarkBaijens Thanks for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean by this I already have `type="text/css"` in my link to the spreadsheet

Comment: Since you got an error on that I thought you had the wrong mime type.

Comment: Does you css work if you remove/comment out the last rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` ?

Comment: @starkeen actually yes it does. I had that line to try get rid of file extensions in the URL though is there a better way to do this in the .htaccess file

Comment: @starkeen it works for my pages the way they were so for example product.php?id=3 now displays fine with css but product/3 doesn't

Comment: This is because the pattern `^(.*)$` matches all http requests including .css and rewrites them to the `/index.php` .You need to fix it so that your rule does not match your css files. Put this condition before the rule to exclude css files `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.css$` .

Comment: @starkeen yeah that makes sense. It's still not working for me though. I've removed that last line and added what you provided and did the same for .js .png .jpg etc,. It still works fine at the un-rewritten url but going to what should be rewrote is not loading any resources

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working