# 500 error on my htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I have a website and I want to write pretty url. At first I have a code that removes the `.php` extension which works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The above code works fine, but however when I add another line to remove the query string I'm getting 500 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Please help

This is the url:

http://bafana-dev.co.za/listing?url=orthopaedic-surgeon/western-cape/cape-town/sunningdale/preyen-naidu

What I want:

http://bafana-dev.co.za/orthopaedic-surgeon/western-cape/cape-town/sunningdale/preyen-naidu

Comment: what do logs reveal?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner the error log does not have anything related with the issue, the logs that I have are the ones I had before adding that line

Comment: when you get error 500 what is your URL, can you post it?

Comment: @DiogoJesus `http://bafana-dev.co.za/listing?url=orthopaedic-surgeon/western-cape/cape-town/sunningdale/preyen-naidu`  this is the url I refreshed the page after editing the line above

Comment: Everything comes up as 404's

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner was working on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
RewriteEngine On
# if a file without .php extension is requested, rewrite it to .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php [L]
# rewrite everything else (except /listing) to /listing?url=
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !listing
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]
```

The 500 error was probably due to the unconditional Rule `RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]` .The rule redirects `/listing` to itself  in a loop mode. I added a Condition above to exclude the destination path.

Comment: Hey thanks, this works.... `http://bafana-dev.co.za/listing?url=cardiothoracic-surgeon/gauteng/germiston/bedford-gardens/lehlohonolo-dongo` is it possible to remove `listing?=` immediately and the styles are not loading now

Comment: @user1 linking a stylesheet to webpage using relative path doesnt work on rewritten urls ,use an absolute path instead ie: `/stylesheet.css` . see this post for info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ /listing?url=$1 [L]
```

Just switch the order like I did, even if you get a white page can you post the current URL of the white page? to see at which point the redirection fails.

Comment: will test now and get back

Comment: The home page just went blank and other pages

Comment: on the last line, add .php at the end of listings. something like `RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ /listing.php?url=$1 [L]`

Comment: Same still no luck.. just 500 errror

Comment: Thanks for the help, working now from the other answer