# URL redirect not loading resources from correct relative source

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I have a bunch of URLs that I want to redirect to a single page.  In my .htaccess file I have...

```
FallbackResource home.php
```

So any link will redirect to that page, where I have a PHP script that takes the URL and loads a page from a mysql table.  I built a test page with no script/style resources and everything worked fine.  However when I added my style and javascript I get the following error:

```
main.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

This error only appears for URLs that have a '`/`' in them.

- So for the url `localhost/home.php` displays my page as it should with
  no content.
- The url `localhost/tax-information` will display the home.php with content
  loaded 'tax-information' as it should.
- The url `localhost/tax-information/school-authority-contact-information` will display home.php with the content
  loaded 'tax-information/school-authority-contact-information' but will throw the error and will as a result
  render no style sheet or have any working javascript.

The errors look like this:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/toh/tax-information/css/style.css".
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I understand that this is caused because the resource being loaded has a '`<`' in the first character, but this doesn't make sense for resources like css.

So I checked my network tab to see what resources are being loaded, and it's loading every resource in the wrong path.

`<style src="css/style.css>` ends up loading localhost/toh/tax-information/css/style.css instead of localhost/css/style.css.  Upon opening that file, it is not CSS but rather is the full HTML of the requested page (thus the '`Unexpected token <`' error).  Even the pictures end up becoming HTML somehow when you click on them in the network tab.  Anything that is loaded through a cdn (so any full URL resource) loads fine.

This only happens for URLs that have a secondary path like (localhost/this/that) but loads the correct resources for anything that is just a primary path (localhost/this).

I can see the problem is caused somehow by FallbackResource and using relative paths for loading resources.  If I change a resource's path to be absolute(say css/style.css -> http://localhost/css/style.css) then it works fine with no issues.  Recoding everything to an absolute path will solve my problem but isn't a practical solution.  This makes me believe my problem is my .htaccess.  Is there another way I can redirect all url paths to a single page and have them load resources through a relative path?

Comment: Any src or href that doesn't begin with a / is relative to the current location, so if you want to load /css/style.css, you should ask for that.

Comment: If you perform a 301 redirection in htaccess keep in mind that browsers keep this information until you remove the cache

Answer (score 1):

You are using a relative path opposed to an absolute path.

When referencing the file `src=“css/css.css”` it was loading the style sheet relative to the location of the file it was being referred to from.

To load a file the root directory of the site use this:`src=“/css/css.css` (with forward slash before path).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a relative path in your `css` and `js` links that is why your relative resources  are loading from a wrong destination instead of the correct one.

To fix this ,you can either use an absolute path in your links ie `/style.css` or use a `Base` tag in the header of your Web page . In between  `<head>` and `</head>` add the following :

```
<base href="/">
```

The base tag above tells webserver to load relative resources from `/` (the home directory) . So if your `css` file is located in the `/style` folder of the root your Web server will try to load it from the real path  `/style/file.css` instead of looking into the requested uri.

Also see this :

[Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)