# Trailing slash in the URL stops image from loading

Tags: php, .htaccess

When I use trailing slash in the URL, the image is stopped from loading. And when I remove the trailing slash from the URL, the image loads without any problem.

If I load the page with http://www.example.com/test/ then image can't be loaded.

If I load the page with http://www.example.com/test then image loads properly

My .htaccess file has following code:

```
# .htaccess mod_rewrite

#Enable mod rewrite
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your using a relative path for your images. When browser url is `/test/`  server thinks `/test` is a directory and tries to append `/test` in front of all relative uris changing your original image links from `image.jpg` to `/test/image.jpg` .

To fix this you need to use an absolute path starting with a leading slash in your `images` and other relative resources. ie : change `image.jpg` to `/image.jpg` or use `base` tag in head section  of your Web page.

```
<base href="/">
```

Similar post :

[Seo Friendly Url css img js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working)

Comment: Before reading your answer, I was using `images/logo.png'`. I replaced it with `/images/logo.png'`, the image didn't still load.

Comment: I agreed with your `<base>` solution but how can I make it work WITHOUT it?

Comment: @uset5307298 You can't make it work without the `base` tag . There is no htaccess or mod-rewrite solution to fill your relative links with the correct base .

Comment: I know `<base>` is must as I have been using it for ages but I don't understand why did you suggest me two options to fix my issue if `<base>` is one and only one working solution? You said - `"change image.jpg to /image.jpg or use base tag in head..."` See the word `or`.