# .htaccess are blocking CSS, javascript, and images from getting access from sub-directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, directory

I search for this but no one solution worked for me.
I already tried many different "solutions" from here, but none of them worked.

I installed WordPress in main root directory of my domain like this  example.com/index.php
So I have a .htaccess for WordPress at the root directory of example.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

after that, I install the other PHP script in sub-directory of the main domain like this  example.com/app/index.php

The .htaccess for PHP script at the sub-directory of example.com/app/index.php :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*?)/page/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1&token=$2
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*?)/page/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1&token=$2
RewriteRule ^download/([^/]*?)/$ /search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^watch/(.+)$ /watch.php?id=$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)$ /index.php?q=&page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(cache/|submit\.php|head\.php|head_mobile\.php|foot\.php|foot_mobile\.php|includes\.php|config\.php) - [F,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^dmca$ /dmca.php
RewriteRule ^privacy$ /privacy.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.php
```

Now my PHP script is not working correctly and all files including CSS, JS, images are not accessible inside sub-directory where PHP script is installed.

I want The URLs should be like these:

```
https://example.com/app/watch/wVS-hHZsAIg
https://example.com/app/contact-us
https://example.com/app/dmca
https://example.com/app/css/style.css
```

But all the above URLs not working and Also it redirect to WordPress installation page and give 404 error like these:

```
https://example.com/watch/wVS-hHZsAIg
https://example.com/contact-us
https://example.com/dmca
https://example.com/css/style.css
```

MY CSS, JS and other relative resources aren't working. this the issue.

And  .htaccess is blocking CSS, javascript, and images from getting access by example.com/app/index.php

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^watch/(.+)$ /watch.php?id=$1  [L]
> ```

All your rewrites (such as the one above) are rewriting the URL to the document root, where WordPress is installed. So, a request for `/app/watch/wVS-hHZsAIg` is being rewritten to `/watch.php?id=wVS-hHZsAIg` (by the above directive), which I assume does not exist, so it will be routed through WordPress, resulting in a 404.

For this `.htaccess` file to work in the `/app` subdirectory, you need to remove the slash prefix from all the *substitution* strings. For example, the above directive should read:

```
RewriteRule ^watch/(.+) watch.php?id=$1 [L]
```

(The trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* is superfluous.)

> ```
> https://example.com/app/contact-us
> ```

The directives you posted look for `contact`, not `contact-us` - so this may be unrelated to the above.

> ```
> https://example.com/app/css/style.css
> ```

Again, this is not related to the above. And is probably caused by incorrect URL paths in your HTML. If you are referencing your CSS with a root-relative URL of the form `/css/style.css` then this is not going to work. You need to either make the URL-path relative (ie. remove the slash prefix, as for the mod_rewrite directives in `.htaccess`), or include the full URL-path in the link (preferable). (This is the opposite of what @starkeen referenced in comments.)

See also, this related question on the Webmasters statck:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css