# htaccess with 2 parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to make a url like this 
if the parameter is only one 
it will be localhost/site/news from index.php?page=news

this is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
```

but if the link like this index.php?page=news&halaman=2

i want to make it like this localhost/site/news/2

i have try this but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+?) index.php?p=$1&halaman=$2 [NC,L]
```

how can i resolve this? Thanks...

Comment: `index.php?p=$1` Looks like your parameter is called `page`, not `p`

Comment: You should redirect everything to index.php and do the routing stuff from there. Otherwise you'll have to adjust your htaccess whenever a new URL is added. Look for PHP routing

Comment: okey, i have change the `p` to `page` but the css and js is mess

Comment: See this post for the CSS and JS solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Comment: @LarsStegelitz The OP is already asking for a general solution with variable arguments. So it is not true that he has to "adjust your htaccess whenever a new URL is added".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt points into the right direction, I only took the liberty to clean it up a bit:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [END,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&halaman=$2 [END,QSD]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).