# Wordpress subfolder multisite does not load css, javascript and images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress multisite with a site in a subfolder; however the css, javascript and images are not loading while I think I have the right rules in htaccess. The hostingparty says none of their settings can overrule the htaccess so it should be working.

https://www.nederweert24.nl/ontdek-nederweert/

My htaccess-rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

What else could cause this issue?

UPDATE

Actually server settings caused this issue. Problem was solved by removing these. Not a good and permanent solution however.
The settings that caused this are these:

```
charset utf-8;
# gzip settings 
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript 
text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript 
application/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf 
font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;
# Leverage browser cache
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires 365d;
```

Comment: Are you using a relative path in your css, js and images?

Comment: yes, I think these are all relative paths

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working