# htaccess rewrite clean url is taking forever to load

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite my URL but when I do in htaccess, the page load is taking forever and when it loads there is no styling and the images are blank, can't seem to tell what the problem is, I don't see any problem in the code, can you help, please ?

## Rewrite clean url for profile.php?user_id=1&section=discussions

```
 RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) profile.php?user_id=$1&section=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241701/seo-friendly-url-css-img-js-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Solution is adding

```
<base href="/">
```

in the head tag